# populate select option list from arraylist

Tags: jquery, sql-server, select

```
function BindRolesDropdownList() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "Dashboard.aspx/PopulateSelectRoleList",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {

                $('#ddlRoles').get(0).options.length = 0;
                $("#ddlRoles").get(0).options[0] = new Option("Select Role", "-1");

                $.each(msg.d, function(index, item) {
                    $("#ddlRoles").get(0).options[$("#ddlRoles").get(0).options.length] = new Option(item.Display, item.Value);
                });
            }
        });
    }
    function BindDropdownList() {
        BindRolesDropdownList();
    }


     [WebMethod]
            public static ArrayList PopulateSelectRoleList()
            {
                //ArrayList lst = new ArrayList();
                //lst = DataAccess.DataAccess.GetRolesArrayList();
                //for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
                //{


                //}


                //return lst;
                return new ArrayList()
                {

                    new { Value = 1, Display = "Male" },
                    new { Value = 2, Display = "Female" }
                };


            }

    public static ArrayList GetRolesArrayList()
            {
                ArrayList aryList = new ArrayList();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds = DBUtility.SQLExecuteDataset("select * from ST_Roles");
                foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    aryList.Add(row);
                }
                return aryList;
            }
```

The above is the code which is filling my select option, my question is how to iterate through the arraylist and return values from database instead of passing static values in the code part which i have commented.

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895205/creating-dropdown-selectoption-elements-with-javascript/7895287#7895287

Comment: i get the values from database into arraylist, if you look at the commented part in the code below that there is return type of arraylist. i want my arraylist which i got from my database to be in that format  return new ArrayList()
                {

                    new { Value = 1, Display = "Male" },
                    new { Value = 2, Display = "Female" }
                };

Comment: Use jQuery.ajax to call into a action/page to get the list of values returned as json. That is where I would start.

Answer (score 0):

```
[WebMethod]
public static ArrayList PopulateSelectRoleList()
{
  return DataAccess.DataAccess.GetRolesArrayList()
    .Select((role, index) => new
    {
        Value = index + 1,
        Display = role
    });
}
```

Comment: the above is displaying nothing in my select option list, i have already tried it. i just want to iterate through the arraylist and bring it to the format   return new ArrayList()
                {

                    new { Value = 1, Display = "Male" },
                    new { Value = 2, Display = "Female" }
                }; how to do this

Comment: can we iterate through the arraylist in jquery and return results from there? instead of doing it in code behind

Comment: Ah, you need to just adapt `GetRolesArrayList` slightly to return a `List<string>` instead of an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Re: not "doing it in code behind", all I see you are really asking for is a way to sunc up the json property names your Web service is returning with those in your JavaScript. I have provided that. You certainly could avoid the whole .Select part of my code with slight changes to your JavaScript, including generating the index with a counter client side (instead of reading item.Value).

Comment: i found the answer i just need to change a line in GetRolesArrayList() method aryList.Add(row); to aryList.Add(new { Value = row["RoleID"].ToString(), Display = row["RoleName"].ToString() }); and it works fine