# can you use jquery to dynamically change the type of an input field?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

**Background Information**

I'm trying to refactor some php / html code.  I have a table full of various rows... each row has a few columns, including an image icon.

I'd like to write some logic so that when someone clicks on this image, the system does two things:

1. creates a drop down list in place of the  tag.
2. gets the values / list for this drop down from an existing drop down on the page.  (Called "location_id").

**HTML Code**

```
  <tr>
    <td id="21581">
       <img src="?module=chrome&amp;uri=pix/tango-user-trash-16x16-gray.png" title="1rack" height="16" width="16" border="0">
     </td>
     <td id="location_name">location1</td> 
     <td>Location1-ABB-01</td>
     <td><input tabindex="1" name="submit" class="edit" src="?module=chrome&amp;uri=pix/pencil-icon.png" id="21581" title="Edit row" type="image" border="0"></td>
    <td><a href="index.php?page=row&amp;row_id=21586">Row Location1-ABB-01</a></td>
   </tr>
```

so specifically I'd like to replace the  that has "location1" as the value with a  drop down that exists else where on the page.  and since the  will have "location1" in the list, I want "located1" to be the selected value.

This is the javascript code I have so far:

**Javascript Code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".edit").click(function(){
                alert(this.id);
                $( "#location_id" ).clone().appendTo("#"+this.id );
        });

});
```

**Question**

This code works in that I end up with a new drop down list in the row, but I'm not sure how to select/highlight the item in the drop down list with the value "21581".  Or, alternatively I could match the  item using the "location_name" value as well.
The challenge I have right now is uniquely identifying the right  box to loop through because the new  that's created from the clone() command has the same name as the existing one.

**EDIT 1**

Here's what the code looks like right now 
(btw.  i can't change my jquery version because this is someone else's code... so I can't use the "on" directive.)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".edit").click(function(e){
                alert(this.id);
                var menu = $( "#location_id" ).clone();
                $(e.currentTarget).replaceWith(menu);
                menu.find('option').each(function(i, opt) {
                // when the value is found, set the 'selected' attribute
                        if($(opt).attr('value') == this.id) $(opt).attr('selected', 'selected');
                 });
        });

});
```

The first alert statement appears correctly - it shows the value in the first td (eg. 21581). The drop down appears and replaces the image... but I need it to replace the location_name value instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895205/creating-dropdown-selectoption-elements-with-javascript, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814512/how-to-create-dropdown-list-dynamically-using-jquery

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown cool.  I didn't know about that.  But that will ADD the select to the input instead of replacing it right?  I need to replace it

Comment: Then you can [`remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/`) the input.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown but then if I want to "find " the text value of the input inside the newly cloned <select> , i'd still have to loop through it right?  the cloning is working... but the newly created <select> list has the same name as the existing one... so I'm not sure how to loop through the newly created one

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I've edited the question so it's a little clearer

Comment: @Jbird posted a nice answer, check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not tested but this should do it (basically)

```
$('input[name="submit"]').on('click', function(e) {
        // create a new select menu
        var menu = $(document.createElement('select'));
        // replace the button that was clicked with the menu
        $(e.currentTarget).replaceWith(menu);
        // add each option from the select menu that contains your options to the newly created menu
        $('select[name="options-target"]').find('option').each(function(i, opt) {
            menu.append($(opt));
        });
});
```

Based on your edit, try this:

```
$('.edit').on('click', function(e) {
       // make your clone
       var menu = $("#location_id").clone();
       // empty the td element then append the menu
       $("#location_name").empty().append(menu);
       // loop through options looking for value 21581
       menu.find('option').each(function(i, opt) {
           // when the value is found, set the 'selected' attribute
           if($(opt).attr('value') == '21581') $(opt).attr('selected', 'selected');
       });
    });
```

Comment: Slight mistype `find('option')`

Comment: Oops - thanks fellas. Edited.

Comment: @Jbird, I've tried to clarify my question a bit.  please see my edit.  basically instead of replacing the image, how would i replace another <td> value that has an id="location_name"

Comment: @dot How about that second example? You're creating an object reference by assigning the clone to the variable 'menu' so you don't need to worry about jquery selecting both menus.

Comment: @Jbird, I'm trying to apply your second example.  but it's not working for me.  See EDIT 1

Comment: @dot - See edit - you just need to empty the td element before appending the new menu

Comment: @Jbird, yes... I'm just not too good with javascript. have to find a way to "find" / identify the correct <td> to replace instead of your e.currentTarget suggestion.  But i will google

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92773/discussion-between-dot-and-jbird).

Comment: Hey @dot - I followed in chat but didn't hear back. One issue i can see with  your latest iteration in your edit is that the context of 'this' has changed because you are inside of the .each() callback function. If you want the id of the button, just use $(evt.currentTarget).attr('id') Please mark the answer as correct if this helped.