# How to generate multiple <select> elements with option tags?

Tags: javascript, html, go-templates

I'm trying to append the defined `select` element to the `document`.
This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17002049/5556365), describes quite well about fixed arrays, but in my case I have a `slice` which is applied to the template by `ExecuteTemplate` method, so the value of `<option>` tags are defined by `slice` values.
Here is my code which does not work, as it should:

```
<html>
<input type="number" id="count">

<select id="select">
   {{ range .Slice }}
       <option value="{{ .Name }}">{{ .Name }}</option>
   {{ end }}
</select>

<div class="test"></div>

<button onclick="generateSelects();">Test</button>
</html>
```

```
 <script>
    function generateSelects() {
      var count = document.getElementById("count").value;
      var i;

      var select = document.getElementById("select");
      var divClass = document.getElementsByClassName("test");


      for (i = 0; i < Number(count); i++) {
        divclass[0].appendChild(select);    
      )   
    }
</script>
```

What am I looking for is about generating `select` list based on the user's input. For example if the user enters `2`, so two `select` menu going to appear on the screen.

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating dropdown <select><option> elements with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895205/creating-dropdown-selectoption-elements-with-javascript)

Comment: @May.D OP does not seem to use JQuery.

Comment: Any bit of googling would have get him the answer, and jQuery is javascript.

Comment: @May.D That's a bit different than the one you've mentioned. In my code the option values are defined outside of the JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all make sure that generated selects all have different IDs, in your example they all have the same id which is "select".
Then instead of appending the "original" select element, try to clone it then add its clone to your div.

What I would do is :

```
function generateSelects() {
      var count = document.getElementById("count").value;
      var i;
      var select = document.getElementById("select");
      var divClass = document.getElementsByClassName("test");

      for (i = 0; i < Number(count); i++) {
        var clone = select.cloneNode(true); // true means clone all childNodes and all event handlers
        clone.id = "some_id";
        divclass[0].appendChild(clone); 
      }  
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It seems that `for` is not working to generate multiple elements by a single button click, so I removed `for` from this function, and defined another function which calls this function multiple times using `for`. And it works! Thanks for your great hint.

Answer (score 0):

To append multiple **select** elements, first you have create a select element. You can not directly get an **elementById** and append different element as child.

```
<script>
    function generateSelects() {
      var count = document.getElementById("count").value;
      var i;
      var divClass = document.getElementsByClassName("test");


      for (i = 0; i < Number(count); i++) {
var option = document.createElement("OPTION");
  option.setAttribute("value", "optionvalue");
var select = document.createElement("SELECT");
select.appendChild(option);
        divclass[0].appendChild(select);    
      )   
    }
</script>
```

Comment: As my option values are not fixed, I have to define them in the html part using range.

Comment: create options dynamically using javascript.